# Why can not use getdata and setdata after document copy

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, clipboard

I want to copy all content from Word to the Clipboard, process it, then send it back to the clipboard.

I use this code and get an exception when it hits `setdata` or `Clipboard.Clear()`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

Doc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Select();
Doc.Application.Selection.Copy();
Doc.Application.Selection.Collapse();
IDataObject clipData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
String clipHtml = null;
if (clipData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Html))
{
clipHtml = (String)clipData.GetData(DataFormats.Html);
}

String html = "<h1>Hello</h1>";
Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;

string begin = "Version:0.9\r\nStartHTML:{0:000000}\r\nEndHTML:{1:000000}"
      + "\r\nStartFragment:{2:000000}\r\nEndFragment:{3:000000}\r\n";

string html_begin = "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n"
      + "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\""
      + " content=\"text/html; charset=" + enc.WebName + "\">\r\n"
      + "<title>HTML clipboard</title>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n"
      + "<!--StartFragment-->";

string html_end = "<!--EndFragment-->\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n";
string begin_sample = String.Format(begin, 0, 0, 0, 0);
int count_begin = enc.GetByteCount(begin_sample);
int count_html_begin = enc.GetByteCount(html_begin);
int count_html = enc.GetByteCount(html);
int count_html_end = enc.GetByteCount(html_end);
string html_total = String.Format(
                            begin
                            , count_begin
                            , count_begin + count_html_begin + count_html + count_html_end
                            , count_begin + count_html_begin
                            , count_begin + count_html_begin + count_html
                            ) + html_begin + html + html_end;

DataObject obj = new DataObject();
obj.SetData(DataFormats.Html, new MemoryStream(
enc.GetBytes(html_total)));
Clipboard.SetDataObject(obj, true, 2, 100);
```

If I comment out `Clipboard.GetDataObject` 
Then `SetDataObject` works well.

But if `Clipboard.Clear()` or `Clipboard.SetDataObject` is retained, I get the same exception:

> ErrorCode: -2147221040

If I comment out `Doc.Application.Selection.Copy()`, `Clipboard.SetDataObject` also works well.

Why can I not use `Copy` and `GetDataObject`, then `SetDataObject` at the same time?

I tried .Net 4 and .Net 4.6.1 got the same results.